# Python webscraping Selenium fails to navigate page and get data after login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium to automate few checkboxes inside an internal Webportal. I am able to successfully login to the page with credentials using Selenium. But after logging in, if I try to navigate to the required page to get content of Webpage, even the login is not happening. And the page remains in the login page itself without being able to login to Webportal.

***Here is the approach which I used:***

> ```
> driver.get('<myLoginURL>')
>
> # maximize window
> driver.maximize_window()
>
> # wait for username input, scroll to it, enter username
> username = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "inputUsername")))
>     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", username)
> username.send_keys("<userID>")
>
> ...... similarly with password.....And then submit...
>
> submit = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn")))
> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", submit)
> submit.click()
> WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY)
>
> driver.get("<URL_To be Navigated to>")
> # WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY).until(driver.get(desired_URL))
> url = driver.current_url
> driver.get(url)
> source = driver.page_source
> ```

***Problems occured:***

1. WebPage will not login with login credentials mentioned.
2. Scraped content gives only login page data (i.e, enter username, enter password)
3. Can someone suggest me good tutorial how to effectively use Selenium to :

- *Scrape the data with tags. Currently I am super confused how to use 'EC.presence_of_element_located' and 'find_element_by_ID'*
- *Reach the webpage I desire to scrape after logging in*
- *how to extract data from the page I want*

Can anyone suggest me what is the mistake I am doing while navigating the page and get the data
Many thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? Being redirected to the login page when fetching "<URL_To be Navigated to">?
Also: The quotes are off there, is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks for that.. I edited the quotes now. Problem is that I wish to navigate to a page inside webportal after logging in. But if I give this new URL as *driver.get(<navigatedURL>)* after code for login, the driver doesnot login and I think it is trying to open navigatedURL without even logging in. So the page stays on just the first page unable even to login

Comment: the login will take a certain amount of time... probably not much, but you are not waiting at all here.  You click submit and then immediately switch pages.  (also, you probably don't need the scroll there... Selenium will automatically scroll into view when click is called.)  Documentation is here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Comment: I also tried as how u suggested to wait. But I end up logging out and staying on the first page. Could you please suggest me any method which I can use? I tried WebDriverWait(driver,DELAY).until(driver.get(new_URL)) and also placed a wait statement before just driver.get(new_URL)

Comment: Or is there a way how to browse and navigate through the sectional tabs after login page is opened. It might be difficult to browse(as it is deep inside) and that is why I am directly trying to give URL to the required ID which I want to open